# link gallary with my camera

Tags: android, camera, gallery

I have made a custom camera app but i want to link the photos saved in a folder to the gallery.How shall I link it?
 My code is:

```
     private void onFileClick2(Option o)
     {
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, "File Clicked: "+f.getPath(),         
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
     Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
     int seconds = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
     Random r = new Random();
     int i1 = r.nextInt();
     File image = new File(f.getPath()+"/"+"picture"+String.valueOf(i1)+".jpg");
     Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
     imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

    startActivityForResult(imageIntent , 1337);
    fill(f);
}
```

Comment: i guess u forgeot to ask the question

Comment: thanks I totally forgot...